# Windows Phone - any form design pattern?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I search a lot of design patterns in Windows Phone. Most of them is connected with separation view from model, but how do we call developing in Windows Phone by using Forms and deal with standard events? Are there any rules / patterns on that that can I use to make it more clear to understand to other developers?

I ask because I want to make not MVVM / MVC or MVP application, and I have to be sure what I will say to my client when he ask what design pattern i've used?

Comment: your clients know about design patterns ?

Comment: Don't talk to your clients about implementation details. If they ask, tell your clients that you would be happy to use whatever pattern that they suggest.

Comment: They won't. Customer want nice looking, fast, bugless and working software. If price is to high, they could reduce any of that demand ( average looking, not so fast, etc). But talking with customer about patterns? Answer them `c#` and they should be happy. And btw, wpf is cool to design nice looking forms and that means stick to MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MV* patterns primarily exist to separate what is displayed (the view) from the logic that interacts with it (the controller, presenter or view model).
There are two main reasons to do this:

1. To make it easier to test the code logic - without needing the UI.
2. To make it easier to reuse your logic in other projects (or platforms)

Obviously there may be scenarios where code is so simple it does not warrant having automated/coded tests written for it. Additionally, you may be writing code that you are certain will never need to be reused in other projects.

If you're writing all your application logic in code behind files then that is your choice. We can't provide your justification for doing this.
There is also no commonly named pattern for writing everything in code behind.

If you don't want to use an MV* pattern then you must have your reason(s) for this and it is these that you explain to your client.

As a freelance developer specialising in Windows Phone and who has worked with lots of code bases created buy other developers, the convention amongst applications developed for Windows Phone is to use some variation on the MVVM pattern. So much so that it is expected. If you are intent on not using this pattern and you want your code to be as understandable to whoever works on it in future then you should just follow general guidelines.

- Follow common conventions
- Be consistent in style, structure and layout
- Name things (variables, methods, classes, etc.) so that they show intent, are not ambiguous and are clear to understand by someone else
- Document anything specific to the application domain
- If any code isn't obvious as to why it exists comment it to explain why

And remember: ["Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/)

Comment: I disagree on one point.  There is a common name for putting everything in the code-behind.  It's called "following a textbook", also known as "a really bad idea"